# Converting one module to standalone Maven project, including a minimal working POM

Tags: maven

I would like to distribute the main artifact sources (main Java and tests) of a multi module project as a simple - standalone - Maven project.

The easy parts of this can be implemented using the maven-source-plugin. This also is able to include the POM in the generated source code jar. However, this is the artefact POM, which refers to the parent POM which is not included in the jar.

Other than creating the POM manually, is there a way to generate a minimal POM which contains the dependencies (extracted from the artifact POM and its parent)?

Comment: Please remove 'maven-plugin' tag. (Hover over a tag to see what it is for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the POM with the flatten-maven-plugin, all parent relations are resolved and you get an equivalent POM without the unnecessary parts.

https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/

Comment: Works very well (except it strips test dependencies, but this can be resolved by the end user easily)